# C#.net tcp client fast incoming data

Tags: .net, performance, tcp, chat

I am working on a client server program for a game that handles logging in, chat, and matchmaking.  This is all done is c#.net.

The problem I am having is with the chat.  The chat works fine, until i start sending chat really fast from another computer.  When i load the client on my laptop and i start smashing the keys and sending it as fast as i can it will come out something like this.

```
Laptop:Hello  <--- this is normal
Laptop:Hello2<EOF>msgLaptop: Hello3      <-- this is what happens.  Hello3 should
   be on the third line without the <EOF>msg.
```

It seems like something is not getting reset but i cannot find where.  the server sends out the information correct because i can see what its doing.

Both client and server use Asynchronous socket connections.  I pretty much send the data as a long string using the beginsend method then have the client or server parse it.

for example  something like "msgtheMessage" msg just says its a message for the chat.

when the data is received it checks for the header which is the 'msg' and then checks for EOF parses those out, then sends it to the chat room.

Is there a good way for handling data that is coming in too fast?

And by the way it doesn't happen like that on the computer where the data is being sent from, only the ones receiving it, even though the server turns around and sends it right back to the computer that sent it the same it.

Comment: the line Laptop:Hello <--- this is normal Laptop:Hello2msgLaptop: Hello3   didn't separate.  theres supposed to be a newline after where i say "this is normal"

Comment: TCP is a *stream*, it is not a packet oriented protocol.  So the messages get put together in an IP packet when you send them fast enough.  Google "Nagle algorithm".  You'll need to add extra data to mark a message.  That can be as simple as sending the string length first.

Comment: Sounds like your message protocol, if you have one, is broken.  If you haven't got one, you need one.

Comment: Thank you guys, setting the no delay property on the socket to true appears to have fixed it.  Thanks a lot guys for your help.  Ive never posted on a forum before but I think i may start.